# Yolov8 TFLite Model on Android

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite, yolov8

I'm trying to run yolov8 model on android. This is the Yolov5Classifier.java file. It works for yolov5 model.Where do I need to change in Yolov5Classifier.java file for yolov8 ? Which parts should I pay attention to ? Yolov5 model input shape (1, 3, 416, 416) output shape (1, 10647, 11)
Yolov8 model input shape (1, 3, 416, 416) and output shape(s) (1, 6, 3549).

Yolov5Classifier.java file

```
public class YoloV5Classifier implements Classifier {

    /**
     * Initializes a native TensorFlow session for classifying images.
     *
     * @param assetManager  The asset manager to be used to load assets.
     * @param modelFilename The filepath of the model GraphDef protocol buffer.
     * @param labelFilename The filepath of label file for classes.
     * @param isQuantized   Boolean representing model is quantized or not
     */
    public static YoloV5Classifier create(
            final AssetManager assetManager,
            final String modelFilename,
            final String labelFilename,
            final boolean isQuantized,
            final int inputSize
            /*final int[] output_width,
            final int[][] masks,
            final int[] anchors*/)
            throws IOException {
        final YoloV5Classifier d = new YoloV5Classifier();
        String actualFilename = labelFilename.split("file:///android_asset/")[0];
        //String actualFilename = labelFilename.split("customclasses.txt")[1];

        InputStream labelsInput = assetManager.open(actualFilename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(labelsInput));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            LOGGER.w(line);
            d.labels.add(line);
        }
        br.close();

        try {
            Interpreter.Options options = (new Interpreter.Options());
            options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
            if (isNNAPI) {
                d.nnapiDelegate = null;
                // Initialize interpreter with NNAPI delegate for Android Pie or above
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    d.nnapiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate();
                    options.addDelegate(d.nnapiDelegate);
                    options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
//                    options.setUseNNAPI(false);
//                    options.setAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(true);
//                    options.setAllowBufferHandleOutput(true);
                    options.setUseNNAPI(true);
                }
            }
            if (isGPU) {
                GpuDelegate.Options gpu_options = new GpuDelegate.Options();
                gpu_options.setPrecisionLossAllowed(true); // It seems that the default is true
                gpu_options.setInferencePreference(GpuDelegate.Options.INFERENCE_PREFERENCE_SUSTAINED_SPEED);
                d.gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate(gpu_options);
                options.addDelegate(d.gpuDelegate);
            }
            d.tfliteModel = Utils.loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename);
            d.tfLite = new Interpreter(d.tfliteModel, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        d.isModelQuantized = isQuantized;
        // Pre-allocate buffers.
        int numBytesPerChannel;
        if (isQuantized) {
            numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
        } else {
            numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
        }
        d.INPUT_SIZE = inputSize;
        d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.INPUT_SIZE * d.INPUT_SIZE * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
        d.imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        d.intValues = new int[d.INPUT_SIZE * d.INPUT_SIZE];

        d.output_box = (int) ((Math.pow((inputSize / 32), 2) + Math.pow((inputSize / 16), 2) + Math.pow((inputSize / 8), 2)) * 3);
//        d.OUTPUT_WIDTH = output_width;
//        d.MASKS = masks;
//        d.ANCHORS = anchors;
        if (d.isModelQuantized){
            Tensor inpten = d.tfLite.getInputTensor(0);
            d.inp_scale = inpten.quantizationParams().getScale();
            d.inp_zero_point = inpten.quantizationParams().getZeroPoint();
            Tensor oupten = d.tfLite.getOutputTensor(0);
            d.oup_scale = oupten.quantizationParams().getScale();
            d.oup_zero_point = oupten.quantizationParams().getZeroPoint();
        }

        int[] shape = d.tfLite.getOutputTensor(0).shape();
        int numClass = shape[shape.length - 1] - 5;
        d.numClass = numClass;
        d.outData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(d.output_box * (numClass + 5) * numBytesPerChannel);
        d.outData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        return d;
    }

    public int getInputSize() {
        return INPUT_SIZE;
    }
    @Override
    public void enableStatLogging(final boolean logStats) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getStatString() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        tfLite.close();
        tfLite = null;
        if (gpuDelegate != null) {
            gpuDelegate.close();
            gpuDelegate = null;
        }
        if (nnapiDelegate != null) {
            nnapiDelegate.close();
            nnapiDelegate = null;
        }
        tfliteModel = null;
    }

    public void setNumThreads(int num_threads) {
        if (tfLite != null) tfLite.setNumThreads(num_threads);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseNNAPI(boolean isChecked) {
//        if (tfLite != null) tfLite.setUseNNAPI(isChecked);
    }

    private void recreateInterpreter() {
        if (tfLite != null) {
            tfLite.close();
            tfLite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);
        }
    }

    public void useGpu() {
        if (gpuDelegate == null) {
            gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate();
            tfliteOptions.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
            recreateInterpreter();
        }
    }

    public void useCPU() {
        recreateInterpreter();
    }

    public void useNNAPI() {
        nnapiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate();
        tfliteOptions.addDelegate(nnapiDelegate);
        recreateInterpreter();
    }

    @Override
    public float getObjThresh() {
        return MainActivity.MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

    // Float model
    private final float IMAGE_MEAN = 0;

    private final float IMAGE_STD = 255.0f;

    //config yolo
    private int INPUT_SIZE = -1;

//    private int[] OUTPUT_WIDTH;
//    private int[][] MASKS;
//    private int[] ANCHORS;
    private  int output_box;

    private static final float[] XYSCALE = new float[]{1.2f, 1.1f, 1.05f};

    private static final int NUM_BOXES_PER_BLOCK = 3;

    // Number of threads in the java app
    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 1;
    private static boolean isNNAPI = false;
    private static boolean isGPU = false;

    private boolean isModelQuantized;

    /** holds a gpu delegate */
    GpuDelegate gpuDelegate = null;
    /** holds an nnapi delegate */
    NnApiDelegate nnapiDelegate = null;

    /** The loaded TensorFlow Lite model. */
    private MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel;

    /** Options for configuring the Interpreter. */
    private final Interpreter.Options tfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

    // Config values.

    // Pre-allocated buffers.
    private Vector<String> labels = new Vector<String>();
    private int[] intValues;

    private ByteBuffer imgData;
    private ByteBuffer outData;

    private Interpreter tfLite;
    private float inp_scale;
    private int inp_zero_point;
    private float oup_scale;
    private int oup_zero_point;
    private int numClass;
    private YoloV5Classifier() {

    }

    //non maximum suppression
    protected ArrayList<Recognition> nms(ArrayList<Recognition> list) {
        ArrayList<Recognition> nmsList = new ArrayList<Recognition>();

        for (int k = 0; k < labels.size(); k++) {
            //1.find max confidence per class
            PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
                    new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
                            50,
                            new Comparator<Recognition>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(final Recognition lhs, final Recognition rhs) {
                                    // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                                    return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
                                }
                            });

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                if (list.get(i).getDetectedClass() == k) {
                    pq.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }

            //2.do non maximum suppression
            while (pq.size() > 0) {
                //insert detection with max confidence
                Recognition[] a = new Recognition[pq.size()];
                Recognition[] detections = pq.toArray(a);
                Recognition max = detections[0];
                nmsList.add(max);
                pq.clear();

                for (int j = 1; j < detections.length; j++) {
                    Recognition detection = detections[j];
                    RectF b = detection.getLocation();
                    if (box_iou(max.getLocation(), b) < mNmsThresh) {
                        pq.add(detection);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nmsList;
    }

    protected float mNmsThresh = 0.6f;

    protected float box_iou(RectF a, RectF b) {
        return box_intersection(a, b) / box_union(a, b);
    }

    protected float box_intersection(RectF a, RectF b) {
        float w = overlap((a.left + a.right) / 2, a.right - a.left,
                (b.left + b.right) / 2, b.right - b.left);
        float h = overlap((a.top + a.bottom) / 2, a.bottom - a.top,
                (b.top + b.bottom) / 2, b.bottom - b.top);
        if (w < 0 || h < 0) return 0;
        float area = w * h;
        return area;
    }

    protected float box_union(RectF a, RectF b) {
        float i = box_intersection(a, b);
        float u = (a.right - a.left) * (a.bottom - a.top) + (b.right - b.left) * (b.bottom - b.top) - i;
        return u;
    }

    protected float overlap(float x1, float w1, float x2, float w2) {
        float l1 = x1 - w1 / 2;
        float l2 = x2 - w2 / 2;
        float left = l1 > l2 ? l1 : l2;
        float r1 = x1 + w1 / 2;
        float r2 = x2 + w2 / 2;
        float right = r1 < r2 ? r1 : r2;
        return right - left;
    }

    protected static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1;
    protected static final int PIXEL_SIZE = 3;

    /**
     * Writes Image data into a {@code ByteBuffer}.
     */
    protected ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
//        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * BATCH_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE * PIXEL_SIZE);
//        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
//        int[] intValues = new int[INPUT_SIZE * INPUT_SIZE];
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        int pixel = 0;

        imgData.rewind();
        for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < INPUT_SIZE; ++j) {
                int pixelValue = intValues[i * INPUT_SIZE + j];
                if (isModelQuantized) {
                    // Quantized model
                    imgData.put((byte) ((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                    imgData.put((byte) ((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                    imgData.put((byte) (((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD / inp_scale + inp_zero_point));
                } else { // Float model
                    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
                }
            }
        }
        return imgData;
    }

    public ArrayList<Recognition> recognizeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer_ = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);

        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();

//        float[][][] outbuf = new float[1][output_box][labels.size() + 5];
        outData.rewind();
        outputMap.put(0, outData);
        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "mObjThresh: " + getObjThresh());

        Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
        tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) outputMap.get(0);
        byteBuffer.rewind();

        ArrayList<Recognition> detections = new ArrayList<Recognition>();

        float[][][] out = new float[1][output_box][numClass + 5];
        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "out[0] detect start");
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numClass + 5; ++j) {
                if (isModelQuantized){
                    out[0][i][j] = oup_scale * (((int) byteBuffer.get() & 0xFF) - oup_zero_point);
                }
                else {
                    out[0][i][j] = byteBuffer.getFloat();
                }
            }
            // Denormalize xywh
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                out[0][i][j] *= getInputSize();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i){
            final int offset = 0;
            final float confidence = out[0][i][4];
            int detectedClass = -1;
            float maxClass = 0;

            final float[] classes = new float[labels.size()];
            for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); ++c) {
                classes[c] = out[0][i][5 + c];
            }

            for (int c = 0; c < labels.size(); ++c) {
                if (classes[c] > maxClass) {
                    detectedClass = c;
                    maxClass = classes[c];
                }
            }

            final float confidenceInClass = maxClass * confidence;
            if (confidenceInClass > getObjThresh()) {
                final float xPos = out[0][i][0];
                final float yPos = out[0][i][1];

                final float w = out[0][i][2];
                final float h = out[0][i][3];
                Log.d("YoloV5Classifier",
                        Float.toString(xPos) + ',' + yPos + ',' + w + ',' + h);

                final RectF rect =
                        new RectF(
                                Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                                Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                                Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));
                detections.add(new Recognition("" + offset, labels.get(detectedClass),
                        confidenceInClass, rect, detectedClass));
                Log.d("other classification", "other classification");

            }
        }

        Log.d("YoloV5Classifier", "detect end");
        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = nms(detections);
//        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = detections;
        return recognitions;
    }

    public boolean checkInvalidateBox(float x, float y, float width, float height, float oriW, float oriH, int intputSize) {
        // (1) (x, y, w, h) --> (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
        float halfHeight = height / 2.0f;
        float halfWidth = width / 2.0f;

        float[] pred_coor = new float[]{x - halfWidth, y - halfHeight, x + halfWidth, y + halfHeight};

        // (2) (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) -> (xmin_org, ymin_org, xmax_org, ymax_org)
        float resize_ratioW = 1.0f * intputSize / oriW;
        float resize_ratioH = 1.0f * intputSize / oriH;

        float resize_ratio = resize_ratioW > resize_ratioH ? resize_ratioH : resize_ratioW; //min

        float dw = (intputSize - resize_ratio * oriW) / 2;
        float dh = (intputSize - resize_ratio * oriH) / 2;

        pred_coor[0] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[0] - dw) / resize_ratio;
        pred_coor[2] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[2] - dw) / resize_ratio;

        pred_coor[1] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[1] - dh) / resize_ratio;
        pred_coor[3] = 1.0f * (pred_coor[3] - dh) / resize_ratio;

        // (3) clip some boxes those are out of range
        pred_coor[0] = pred_coor[0] > 0 ? pred_coor[0] : 0;
        pred_coor[1] = pred_coor[1] > 0 ? pred_coor[1] : 0;

        pred_coor[2] = pred_coor[2] < (oriW - 1) ? pred_coor[2] : (oriW - 1);
        pred_coor[3] = pred_coor[3] < (oriH - 1) ? pred_coor[3] : (oriH - 1);

        if ((pred_coor[0] > pred_coor[2]) || (pred_coor[1] > pred_coor[3])) {
            pred_coor[0] = 0;
            pred_coor[1] = 0;
            pred_coor[2] = 0;
            pred_coor[3] = 0;
        }

        // (4) discard some invalid boxes
        float temp1 = pred_coor[2] - pred_coor[0];
        float temp2 = pred_coor[3] - pred_coor[1];
        float temp = temp1 * temp2;
        if (temp < 0) {
            Log.e("checkInvalidateBox", "temp < 0");
            return false;
        }
        if (Math.sqrt(temp) > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
            Log.e("checkInvalidateBox", "temp max");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }



}
```